# Obtaining a grill mesh with not all faces aligned

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I am new to Blender and currently practicing few meshes.

I am interested in designing cattle catcher for locomotives. Something as shown in the below picture.

[image: Cattle Catcher]

Is there any easy technique in Blender 2.8 to get this mesh done?

Thanks. Any help would be deeply appreciated.